# Move variable add-tot-cart button before dropdowns in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I'm trying to complete a site in WooCommerce using the storefront theme.

The product itself is a variable product, so it contains variations. I'd like to 
move the variations to just below the add to cart.

Please see here: 
https://ledpanellighting.co.uk/shop/colour/4000k/lled23pnl-w40-litelite-23w-led-panel-natural-white-4000k/

I'd like the dimming option to appear under the add to cart.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Justin,

Truth be told, I've already done all the above.

Thanks for your assistance, I'll try on the WP forums. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd already tried coding it yourself, why wouldn't you post the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an expert but what you want is to move the Variations under the add to cart button(?).

I think you can use `actions`.

Just remove the current add to cart button and call him in earlier.

I use this to have the same result in my default Storefront Theme. (Putting the variations options under the add to cart option.)

BTW: I see that you have a heavily customised storefront theme, so i think that my code may not work in your theme unless you share which filters are you moving to have that layout.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button',25 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
```

This is how it look is in my default storefront, i hope is what you are looking for. 
[image: Variations under Add to Cart Button]

Comment: Hi Syntax_Error,

Thankyou for your response. Yes, this is what I'm looking at doing, so thankyou for the assistance.

To the person who modified the title of the post - it's related to the Storefront Theme which itself makes extremely heavy use of hooks. So therefore, it wouldn't be particularly relevant to any default themes. Thanks for changing the title though...

Syntax_Error - I've just tried this addition and it didn't work. Glad we're on the same path though.

Comment: Turns out the solution was in the hook. Storefront has a lot of hooks, hence the difficulty.

Here's the code for anyone else:

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );